# Horizontal Align elements inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, scrollview, android-relativelayout

So my problem is the following... I have a RelativeLayout which has 3 main elements. A column with 2 buttons on the left,  another on the Right and a ScrollView layout on the center which contains a ViewPager and a button.

The button aligns just fine to it's parent. But I can not get the ViewPager to align itself.

Here is my XML layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/leftButtons"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    >

    <Space
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftArrowBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/left_arrow"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_selector"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/leftArrowBtnAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/left_arrow"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_selector_all" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/middleLayouts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftButtons"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightButtons"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="35dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/selectDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:background="@drawable/default_button_rounded"
            android:drawablePadding="35dip"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_date_light"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="25dip"
            android:paddingRight="25dip"
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:text="@string/monthly_statistics_"
            android:textColor="@color/light_bg" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rightButtons"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    >
    <Space
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip" />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightArrowbtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_selector"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/rightArrowbtnAll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right_selector_all" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a ScreenShot of how it looks... 
[image]

And here is a Screenshot of the Layout Editor that shows me that the table should be aligned....

I've tried all Kind of layouts and, gravitys, etc.. but I can not get it to center! :(

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the linear layout, inside the scrollview, should have a width of match_parent instead of wrap_content

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/middleLayouts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftButtons"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rightButtons"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="35dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
```

Comment: I tried all types of widths and wraping contents before I posted here. So that wasn't my problem. I answered my question with what was happening. Thanks anyways ")

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. My problem is that I was using a `TableLayout` to create the tables and the `TableLayout` sets it's width to `match_parent` always. So because of that the TableLayout was using the entire width and not being centered. I switched from a `TableLayout` to a `LinearLayout` with vertical `TableRows` and works just fine now. :)